# ListPreference & SwitchPreference doesn't work

Tags: java, xml, apk, apktool

I have reverse engineered an app (Settings.apk)
all i want to do is,

1. I want to make a SwitchPreference, on my case that i wanted to create a switch selector that will turn off / turn on double tap to wake for my device (i added it because that feature was absent, but anyway my device supports the feature)
   here is my xml, i created the SwitchPreference on the accesibilty section of Settings app

[here](https://github.com/zomaru/DOS/blob/master/accesibility_settings.xml)

2. I also created a ListPreference in the xml, i want to create a list selector that was in purpose of choosing the CPU freq & I/O Scheduler. I have also done doing it  but it doesn't work as it intended to be.
   the ListPreference's xml code is also on accesibility xml . What should i add to make both of them functional?

notice me if my question was offtop,
thank you.